# Find a file from innermost to outermost directory (Recursive)

Tags: c#, recursion

I am trying to search for a file in a given directory.
I have to find the file from the innermost directory and if not found traverse recursively 1 step up.

Ex: Iteration 1:
    Search for file in : D:\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Folder4

Ex: Iteration 2:
    Search for file in : D:\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\

Ex: Iteration 3:
    Search for file in : D:\Folder1\Folder2\

My Code:

```
private string findTheFile(string path)
    {

        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "filename.txt", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

        if (files.Length == 1)
            return files[0].ToString();    //File found, return the file's path.
        else
            findTheFile(Path.GetDirectoryName(path));// File not found, recursively search the parent folder.

        return null; // Return null if file not found.
    }
```

What is happening:
 The code works to one extent, meaning the file location is found. But instead of returning the value, the control continues to the else part.

Please guide me when I have gone wrong.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, you should return the result of recursive method:

```
private string findTheFile(string path)
    {

        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "filename.txt", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

        if (files.Length == 1)
            return files[0].ToString();
        else
            return findTheFile(Path.GetDirectoryName(path)); /* You should return your result here */

        return null;
    }
```

If you don't return the result of `findTheFile` method, the `null` value will be returned.

Comment: It Worked, All I had to do in the else part was not call the function directly. But use a return statement. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by "continues to the else part". But your code should work if you fix it like this:

```
private string findTheFile(string path)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
    {
        return null;
    }

    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "filename.txt", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

    if (files.Length == 1)
        return files[0];    //File found, return the file's path.

    return findTheFile(Path.GetDirectoryName(path)); // File not found, recursively search the parent folder.
}
```